# Is it possible to push a build directly to nexus instance running downstream as a proxy repository?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

In my organization we have one instance of nexus that acts as a central repository for maintaining builds. In the current setup when we try to deploy a build into production, the deployment entity queries the nexus instance to fetch the appropriate build. I am trying to rearchitect the nexus setup and create nexus instances local to every datacenter in order to facilitate the deployment entity to quickly fetch the artifact.

I am trying to dilute this dependency between our central repository and the deployment entity. I very well understand the data flow in nexus proxy repository setup (upstream to downstream), but i still want to give this a shot. Is it possible to directly push in downstream (proxy) instance if the upstream nexus instance is offline? This will be more of an emergency strategy to make the artifacts available in datacenters even if the central nexus instance is down for some reason.

I am not sure if directly copying the artifact (over ssh) in DC instance at sonatype-work/nexus/storage/ then restarting nexus service (for reindexing) would get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Smart Proxy is a feature of Nexus Pro that replaces the polling of repositories with a publish - subscribe model. You can configure an upstream repo to publish any new deployment and then configure downstream repos to automatically download any new upstream components. This would exactly implement your desired setup of a master Nexus that receives the deployments and the downstream instances in the local datacenters mirroring it down.

See more about [Smart Proxy in the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/smartproxy.html).

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help in my case because i am trying to handle the case where upstream repo is offline and in order to keep the deployment entity unblocked for emergency releases i should be able to push the artifacts directly to downstream nexus instances living in the datacenter. The deployment entity communicates only with the downstream instances.

Comment: You if you set up smart proxy between your master, your downstream repos and your datacenter repos you are set..